# Elbow method for tuning DBSCAN when the minimum number of points per cluster is one

Tags: clustering, hyperparameter, k-nearest-neighbour, dbscan

The elbow method calls for setting the number of nearest neighbors (let's call it $k$) to the minimum number of points for a cluster (let's call it $m$), but what do you do when $m\leftarrow1$? Is the elbow method still usable in this situation, and if so, how do you determine $k$ since setting $k$ equal to one results in all the distances equalling zero?

For some reason this was flagged as a programming question when this is a generic question pertaining to hyperparameters.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you call this the "elbow method" as there's no elbow in it. Furthermore, $k=1$ doesn't make sense because the cluster concept of DBSCAN is that clusters are high density regions, and a single point alone can't indicate a high density. If you really want to declare single points clusters and use DBSCAN (despite this combination not looking particularly convincing), you could use a higher value of $k$/minPts and declare all points that are not in any cluster one-point clusters.